# How to summon Monad[IO]?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

In my program, I am using this fragment in many places:

```
def ... (implicit val m: Monad[F])
```

I want to initialize m in main class but it always results in null:

```
implicit override val m: Monad[IO] = Monad[IO] //m is null
```

However, it works for tests where I do:

```
implicit override val m: Monad[Id] = Monad[Id]
```

I know that IO is from effects and Id is from core but I don't know how to summon IO. I am using IOApp/Resources to init an app.

Comment: It is always in scope, why you want to provide it yourself?

Comment: I have this Logging trait, which takes F. I have to pass it somehow. 
`trait LoggingF[F[_]] {
  val log: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)
  implicit val m: Monad[F]

  def logF(message: String): F[Unit] = m.pure(log.info(message))
}`

Comment: That trait is not really well modelled, is that yours?

Comment: Yes it's mine, do you have any suggestion how this should be done?

Comment: For this use case the best would be to use [**log4cats**](https://github.com/typelevel/log4cats) - but, in general, you would model things like [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/aIHVjlxgS92loNj1icgTIg/2) note that the `LoggingF` capability trait doesn't include any information about `F`.

Comment: Thank you, I should definitely go this way!